# Class with different access: read-only to the many, writable to the privileged

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, private, derived-class

I have some large amounts of strings grouped in some classes, all grouped in one final giant class. This class must be filled up by another class and its immutable content exposed to some clients. (Of course, these classes are more complex, this is a simplified schematic representation.)

Solution 1:

```
class A
{
friend class M;

private:
    B m_b;
    C m_c;
    D m_d;

public:
    const B& GetB() const { return m_b;}
    const C& GetC() const { return m_C;}
    const D& GetD() const { return m_D;}

private:
    B& GetB() { return m_b;}
    C& GetC() { return m_C;}
    D& GetD() { return m_D;}
}
```

where B is something like:

```
class B
{
friend class M;

private:
    std::string m_camel;
    std::string m_pink;
    std::string m_vandergraaf;

public:
    const std::string& Camel() const { return m_camel;}
    const std::string& PinkFloyd() const { return m_pink;}
    const std::string& VanDerGraafGenerator() const { return m_vandergraaf;}

private:
    void SetCamel(const char* prog) { m_camel = prog;}
    void SetPinkFloyd(const char* prog) { m_pink = prog;}
    void SetVanDerGraafGenerator(const char* prog) { m_vandergraaf = prog;}
}
```

A better solution, that avoids `friend` for `protected` is to expose the write access class to M and the base one, read-only to the world.

Solution 2:

```
class A
{
protected:
    B m_b;
    C m_c;
    D m_d;

public:
    const B& GetB() const { return m_b;}
    const C& GetC() const { return m_C;}
    const D& GetD() const { return m_D;}
}

//  only visible to M
class A_Write: public A
{
public:
    B& GetB() { return m_b;}
    C& GetC() { return m_C;}
    D& GetD() { return m_D;}
}
```

Same thing for B, maybe. Not a very good solution since the clients can also derive their own classes.

A better but more constraint variant is solution 3:

```
class A
{
private:
    const B m_b;
    const C m_c;
    const D m_d;

public:
    const B& GetB() const { return m_b;}
    const C& GetC() const { return m_C;}
    const D& GetD() const { return m_D;}

protected:
    A(const B& b, const C& c, const D& d): m_b(), m_c(c), m_d(d) {}
}

//  only visible to M
class A_Write: public A
{
public:
    A_Write(const B& b, const C& c, const D& d): A(b, c, d) {}
}
```

My preferred solution is 4, which is ... 3 but with B,C,D as simple `struct`s instead of `class`es. So M can do anything it wants directly in B, C, D, then construct a A_Write.

Any better ideas ?

Comment: That's what a proxy can be used for, to reduce visibility of an interface. Have you ever tried it?

Comment: Do you mean PIMPL ? This one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern ?  Do you mean some virtual ?
My first thought is this would be too heavy for my case. I have to sleep for now, bye!

Comment: Could you please articulate your thoughts in an answer? With some class schema?

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach could be to use a proxy that reduces the interface of your class.
The class `M` will instantiate/receive an instance of `S` (so as to be able to modify it using its interface), but it will return a proxy `P` to the readers (that won't manage to modify it).
It follows a minimal example:

```
struct S {
    void value(int v) noexcept { t = v; }
    int value() const noexcept { return t; }
private:
    int t{0};
};

struct P {
    P(S& s): b{s} { }
    int value() const noexcept { return b.value(); }
private:
    S& b;
};

int main() {
    // the class: full interface
    S s;
    // the proxy: reduced interface
    P p{s};
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I think that P can return a const reference to S (and the others) to avoid writing the "proxy" functions (value) for all members.

Comment: The second solution was preferred by my company, although yours is better since it separates the classes.